# Detect if mobile user and desktop is same

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular7

I want to detect users coming on my website and check the repeated users.
So, if a user access my website from desktop browser and then let's suppose next day same user access my site from mobile browser. How do i know that this mobile user is same that came yesterday through desktop, so that i can increase number of visit of user instead of creating a new user?

Browsers don't share the cookie id , so using cookie id will not work i guess.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Have a simple login functionality in your website. If not possible, you can have a modal kinda thing that takes the email of the user and check if the email (or any other information) exists in your database and you can increment the number of visits. Keep **localStorage** so that Next time he/she logs in from the same device the modal need not pop up.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will add login functionality later.

Answer (score 1):

Does your website require users to sign in?
- If yes, then it is simply to store an incremental number of visits, and increase it each time an user access your site.
- If no, it's not possible.